# Prevent sequential repeated chars using Regular Expression

Tags: regex

I'm trying to learn regular expression. I wrote this regex.

```
^[a-zA-Z]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9.]*@{1}([a-z]+).[a-z]{2,5}$
```

in fact, I'm not going to use this as an email validator. just testing.
results of this regex are :

```
exchange@stack.com          // match
s.@.com                     // not
@overflow.c@com             // not
stack..@o.net               // match
stackov@@.com               // not
@overflow.com@s.stack       // not
1#stack.@s.com              // not
```

but as you see, `stack..@o.net` is also known as a valid expression.
How can I detect those sequentially repeated `.`s in string?

Comment: `[a-zA-Z0-9.]` => `([a-zA-Z0-9]|(?<!\.).)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You don't need `{1}` in your regex.
- You need to escape dot in regex.

If your regex supports [lookahead feature](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) then you can use this regex:

```
^(?!.*?\.\.)[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9.]*@([a-z]+)\.[a-z]{2,5}$
```

Comment: as the website you linked, `?!` means something not followed by something, but I can't understand `(?!.*?\.\.)` in your regex. could you please explain it. thanks.

Comment: `(?!.*?\.\.)` means match the regex is there is no `..` anywhere in the input (since it is followed by `.*?`)

Answer (score 1):

Well, the simplest form of an e-mail address would be as follows :

```
^\w+@(\w+\.)+\w+$
```

**Explanation :**

- (Start of the string = `^`)
- Match any character
- Followed by `@`
- Match any character, followed by a dot (as many times a possible)
- Match any character (= the tld, like `.com`, `.org`, etc)
- (End of the string = `$`)

**Demo :**

http://regexr.com?38edd